# HTML Purifier only close unclosed tags

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

Using HTML PURIFIER Only to close unclosed tags without removing XSS vulnerability or anything else ?

Official website: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Use HTML PURIFIER only for unclosed tags (Preventing from removing classes, styles and others) :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: Use HTML PURIFIER only for unclosed tags :)

Comment: That's still not a question..

Comment: Use HTML PURIFIER only for unclosed tags (Preventing from removing classes, styles and others) :)

Comment: I think your question is `Can you use the HTML PURIFIER to only (without removing XSS vulnerability or anything else) close unclosed tags?` which I can't answer, never used that service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize HTML Purifier's built in HTML parser to do this by simply overriding the "strategy", which is responsible for processing tokens. Here is how to do it:

```
include_once 'library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$raw = '<a href="onclick:xss()">foo';

class HTMLPurifier_Strategy_Null extends HTMLPurifier_Strategy {
    public function execute($tokens, $config, $context) {
        return $tokens;
    }
}

class HTMLLinter extends HTMLPurifier {
    public function __construct($config = null) {
        parent::__construct($config);
        $this->strategy = new HTMLPurifier_Strategy_Null();
    }
}

$linter = new HTMLLinter();
echo $linter->purify($raw);
```

Comment: DOM require server configuration to be installed, something like HTML PURIFIER are perfect for my need :) thank's for your contribution.

Comment: OK, here is one way to do it.

Comment: Awesome ! thank you so much, this resolved my problem :)